# How to display all the results from a table from MySQL via static PHP code when the table fields are not always the same

Tags: php, html

How to display all the results from a table from MySQL via static PHP code when the table fields are not always the same?

Viable example:
I am working on a site that gives the user the option to create custom tables in the MySQL database via PHP code. There is also a page (with static PHP code) that should display the custom database tables in a HTML table using PHP code.

I use mysqli and not PDO.

Example code of what I know:

```
<?php
$db_table = mysqli_query($db_link,"SELECT * FROM custom_table");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_field($db_table)) {
$column_name = $row->name;
?>
<th><?php echo $column_name; ?></th>
<?php
}
?>
```

The above will display all the column names, but how do I do to display all the column names and all the values from the table below this column names ?

I do not know all the row names, so I can't define them using $row1 = $row['table_field']; and then echo it into the HTML table.

Comment: `foreach($row as $cell){echo $cell;};`

Comment: I am using this now: <table class='table'>

<tr>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_field($db_table)) {
$column_name = $row->name;
?>
<th><?php echo $column_name; ?></th>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_table)) {
?>
<tr>
<?php
foreach($row as $cell){
?>
<td><?php echo $cell; ?></td>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>

And it's displaying the values multiple times.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: It shows all the rows but they are repeating themselves because they are in a while loop. How can I integrate foreach in a while loop and show all the results without them being multiplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$header=true;
$header_row=''; $row_data='';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_table)) {
      $row_data.='<tr>';
      foreach($row as $key=>$value){
         if($header){
           $header_row.='<th>'.$key.'</th>';
         }
         $row_data.'<td>'.$value.'</td>';
      }
      $header=false; # stop after first run through as we have all header fields
      $row_data.='</tr>';
 }
 echo '<table><tr>'.$header_row.'</tr>'.$row_data.'</table>';
```

didn't validate this but you should get the idea

Comment: there are other more eloquent ways to approach this, and make the output more usable for reference, but this walks you through the approach a little more plainly